# How to make an inner block be always top on other layers?

Tags: css

I have a basic design on header, banner and menu. Menu is put into the header block and banner is at the same layer to the header using the same z-index. No matter how large of number of the z-index I set to the menu and greater than the banner, the menu is still behind the banner. Below is the code I apply, how can I always make the menu always on top of any layers?

Demo can be found from http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/s0690n29/

HTML

```
<div class="header">Header Area
    <div class="menu">Menu Area</div>
</div>
<div class="banner">Banner</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.header {
    z-index: 10;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
.menu {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 20;
}
.banner {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
    margin-top -10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context and http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/zindex.html

Answer (score 1):

You have to set `z-index` for header greater than banner:

```
div {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
.header {
    z-index: 20; /* change this */
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5) !important;
}
.menu {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.5);
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 5%;
    height: 300px;
    z-index: 20;
}
.banner {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.8);
    margin-top -10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:10;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/s0690n29/1/

Comment: In my case, I set the height to the header as 100px, there is no problem, but how if I set to auto and make the header's height be adjustable depending on the content in it? When I change the height to the header to auto, then the banner will be dropped down and the menu fully inside the header but not look like on top of it. Result at http://jsfiddle.net/s0690n29/1/

Comment: than you have to make your menu to have `position` set to `absolute` and work around it